# Can you please identify the error in this code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that is giving me a compile error:

> Expected: Expression and it specifically highlights the first IF of
>   the formula.

Code:

```
Sub ProduceTheListOfRecourseAccounts()

' Run formulas to populate the recourseable accounts on the Recourse Items Page

    Sheets("Recourse Items").Range("A2:A & LastRow).FormulaArray = "=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Formula sheet'!$A:$F,SMALL(IF('Formula sheet'!E:E>'WBC Recourse Summary'!$E$15,ROW('Formula sheet'!A:A)),ROW('Formula sheet'!1:1)),1)),"""",INDEX('Formula sheet'!$A:$F,SMALL(IF('Formula sheet'!E:E>'WBC Recourse Summary'!$E$15,ROW('Formula sheet'!A:A)),ROW('Formula sheet'!1:1)),1))"

End Sub
```

Please help me identify what I am doing wrong.  This is my first VBA array, all normal formulas are working well in VBA.

Many thanks

Comment: `Range("A2:A & LastRow).....` is missing the closing quotation mark. It should be `Range("A2:A" & LastRow)....`

Comment: Perfect, Good spot, thanks for this

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close your string.  You want:

```
"A2:A" & LastRow
```

Looks like this was answered in a comment.

Comment: Thanks :) looking at the code too long I just didn't notice that